# Using the universal selector (*) in a click event to select only that clicked and not parents

Tags: jquery

I'm developing a DOM inspector bookmarklet. I need the user to be able to click on anything in the page, therefore I have to use the universal selector (*) to attach a click event to. However, when an item is clicked via this selector, I get returned the selected item plus every parent. How do I get just the selected item so I can work with that?

```
$(document).on("click", "*", function() {
    alert(this);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "*", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

jQuery Documentation:  http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 2):

> "I need the user to be able to click on anything in the page, therefore I have to use the universal selector (*) to attach a click event to."

You don't need the universal selector, in fact you don't need that second parameter to specify a selector at all. When the document receives the click event it can determine which element the event started with using the [`event.target` property](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/):

```
$(document).on("click", function(event) {
    // event.target is the element you care about
    alert(event.target.id);  // or whatever
    ...

});
```

Comment: you're right, although the caveat is (in either case) that the OP's event handler must be registered before any other event handler to ensure it gets first bite at any events.

Comment: @Alnitak - Even if the above is registered first it still wouldn't (necessarily) get first bite, because wouldn't a handler bound directly to the element always be called before a delegated handler bound to the document?

Comment: you mean an `onclick="..."` handler?  Yes, although it's possible to remove those, add this, and then re-insert the original using `addEventListener`.

Comment: @Alnitak - No, I mean `$("#someElementId").click(...`. - http://jsfiddle.net/xuCya/