# Detect URL change in querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I am adding some script on a Shopify product page where I need to detect the URL change which happens on selection of a product option (handled by Shopify) for further use.

The URL change occurs when variants are selected with the query parameter (question mark) like this:

```
Variant 1 - my.shopify.domain/products/product1?variant=1234
Variant 2 - my.shopify.domain/products/product1?variant=5678
```

I have tried adding the 'hashchange' event but then realized it only works for '#' which is not the case here.

What should I do?

Comment: When the URL changes does the page actually unload/reload? If so you will need to write some logic to detect the change between requests. If not, then you can try [`popstate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event), although the chances of that working depend on how the URL gets changed

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The URL does not reload. It is handled by an Event Listener by Shopify.
You can check this URL as example - 
https://thesmilemorestore.com/products/smile-more-acid-wash-tees?variant=19692968050745

Comment: Check every 2 seconds using setInterval() (provided there is no server call) ?

Comment: @vivek_23 That is an option but there will still be cases when user selects an option and quickly adds to cart or something like that and the script gets the wrong data.

Comment: @user3884753 Attach a click event universally ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15950585/using-the-universal-selector-in-a-click-event-to-select-only-that-clicked-an

Comment: @vivek_23 For now I have implemented the setInterval method. Click event target will change with different themes hence won't work every time.

Comment: @user3884753 Well, I presume it should be independent of theme. Something like this https://jsfiddle.net/1xea4f0g/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199081/discussion-between-user3884753-and-vivek-23).

Comment: Can you put a listener on product variant select change? The url that changes here is basically the selected variant id .. dig into the code a little bit, you'll find the select  element in the product form on the page.

Comment: Why not use onchange on the variant field, instead of the url change listener? `$("#SingleOptionSelector-0").change(function(){.....}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please paste this script in your product.liquid file

```
<script>
  var firstTimeUrl = document.URL;
  document.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var currentPageUrl = document.URL;
  var url = new URL(currentPageUrl);
  var isVariantUrl = url.searchParams.get("variant");
  currentPageUrl = isVariantUrl ? currentPageUrl :isVariantUrl;
    if(currentPageUrl && firstTimeUrl != currentPageUrl) {
      firstTimeUrl = currentPageUrl;
      console.log('variant_id: '+isVariantUrl+'')
    }
  });
</script>
```